# How to get rid of the _N for Keras metric names?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, metrics, tf.keras

I am using the "tensorflow" keras. ie. i did:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

Not sure if this is different from Keras with TF as backend. I am on TF 1.14.0 and running this on google colab.

The problem is that each time I re-created a model (or recompile), _N will be appended to the metrics. You can see this in the printout during training, and also as keys to history.history.

```
Epoch 1/100
32206/32206 [==============================] - 4s 138us/sample - loss: 0.8918 - precision_4: 0.6396 - recall_4: 0.4613 - val_loss: 5.5533 - val_precision_4: 0.0323 - val_recall_4: 0.0492
Epoch 2/100
```

I am not sure if this is important for Keras to work properly but these names are an inconvenience when i tried to access them in the history. I could write more code to parse them but I like to know if i can just enforce the names in the first place. Usually, when i re-instantiated the model (or recreate from functional API), i don't intend to keep around the old version (i just overwrite it into "model"). So I am just not sure if those "_N" stuff has any importance than just the names. Would Keras somehow make use of them internally? such that I may just be better off living with those names and just parse them out properly when I need to access them later.

Comment: I have never seen this, please try with keras (not the same as tf.keras) and report back results.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro. I will come around and try what you said next chance. But I just found out 'name' is an argument to the metrics. So i am trying keras.metrics.Precision(name='Precision') and see if i can force the metrics name to stay the same all the time.

Comment: keras metrics don't have such names, that is specific to tf.keras. Are you using TensorFlow 2.0?

Comment: I am on tf 1.14.0. I tried adding to the name param and so far so good, i think thats my solution for now.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision')
keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall')
```

when specifying your metrics, and it will stick to the name you give it, in training print out, as well as in history.history

So far, I haven't found any trouble with doing this. So this is the solution for now until proven otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I also discovered another:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```

I noticed the default layer names started from a clean slate. I suspect this should also happen to those metric _N stuff, although i didn't try since i found the solution (using explicit naming).