# Keras adds a number after metric key

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, metrics

I use TensoFlow version 2.4.0 and Keras on Windows 11, and I want to add a `ModelCheckpoint` callback monitoring `auc`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

try: # Atttempt to get rid of any model, history from previous runs
    del model
    del history
except:
    print('No model to delete')

checkpoint_filepath = "checkpoint"
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_auc',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss= 'binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])

history = model.fit(..., callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])
```

Everything is fine since `val_auc` exists in the `history.history.keys()`.
However, if I run the code again (in a Jupyter notebook) the next time the key becomes: `val_auc_1`.

And of course `ModelCheckpoint` does not work.

I have to restart the kernel to get rid of this annoying `_1` at the end of the key.

One solution suggested by `keras` docs is to run `model.fit` just for 1 epoch to get the `history.history.keys()`, and then use it in the `ModelCheckpoint`. But this is really clumsy. Is there a way to get the metric keys after `model.compile` without running `model.fit`? Or else is it possible to avoid this `_1` somehow?

Comment: Not sure of this, but you could maybe give a name to the AUC metric`tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='myauc')`

Comment: @elbe it actually works! Now the `auc` keys are always `myauc` and `val_myauc`. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rid of the \_N for Keras metric names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120261/how-to-get-rid-of-the-n-for-keras-metric-names)

Answer (score 1):

So the first time you run the code block containing `tf.keras.metrics.AUC()` you generate an instance of this class which by default is given the name 'auc'. It seems that this instance is being stored in memory and so when you run `tf.keras.metrics.AUC()` again it creates a second instance of this class. The behaviour for these types of classes is to assign unique names to each instance of the class (the keras function for assigning names to layers is [here](https://github.com/keras-team/tf-keras/blob/5003d8fbe4097808614daf63686fac4b9522b81d/tf_keras/backend.py#L1174)), and so a '_1' is appended to the second instance. You can see this behaviour if you run e.g.:

```
a1 = tf.keras.metrics.AUC()
a2 = tf.keras.metrics.AUC()
print(f'a1 name: {​a1.name}​')
print(f'a2 name: {​a2.name}​')
```

As pointed out in the comment by @elbe, you can solve this by assigning a name when you create the instance i.e. `tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc')`; or as you have already pointed out you can restart the kernel.